# How to display string.xml attributes same by using Typeface

Tags: android

I want to display string.xml attributes as like same by using Typeface or in any other method in TabActivity setIndicator().

```
<string name="telugu">తెలుగు</string>

Intent a = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("Ram").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.telugu)).setContent(a);
Hst.addTab(tSpc);
```

Here is complete code of mine 
when i am calling Typeface in onCreate(); method its crashes.

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ActivityStart extends TabActivity {

TextView frst,scnd,thrd;

TabHost tHst;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_start);
    //      frst=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.frsttxt);
    Typeface gautami_font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
    frst.setTypeface(gautami_font);
    frst.setText(getString(R.string.first));


    tHst=getTabHost();
    TabSpec tSpc;

    Intent a = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("Ram").setIndicator(frst).setContent(a);

    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
    Intent b = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.second)).setContent(b);
    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
    Intent c = new Intent(this,FrameActivity.class);
    tSpc=tHst.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.third)).setContent(c);
    tHst.addTab(tSpc);
}
```

}

error:

```
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.changelanguage/com.example.changelanguage.ActivityStart}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.example.changelanguage.ActivityStart.onCreate(ActivityStart.java:23)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-26 05:57:11.649: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     ... 11 more
```

launcher Activity Added now when select a button it should display according to the selected language

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button tel,eng;
Locale loc_lang;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.telugu);
    eng=(Button) findViewById(R.id.english);

    tel.setOnClickListener(this);
    eng.setOnClickListener(this);
    Typeface gautami_font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
    tel.setTypeface(gautami_font);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.telugu:
        setLang("te");

        break;
    case R.id.english:
        setLang("en");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

private void setLang(String string) {
    loc_lang=new Locale(string);
    Resources rsc= getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = rsc.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration cnf = rsc.getConfiguration();
    cnf.locale=loc_lang;
    rsc.updateConfiguration(cnf, dm);
    Intent setng_lang=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityStart.class);
    startActivity(setng_lang);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/nameoffont.otf");
title.setTypeface(face);
title.setText(getString(R.string.telugu));
```

Comment: you should add font file in assets/fonts folder, enjoy!!

Comment: Hi i have added font file in assets even it crashes